# Accessing a dropwizard Bundle instance from guiceModule

Tags: java, mongodb, guice, dropwizard

I am new to dropwizard, and am using GuiceBundle and MongoBundle in my application.
The MongoClient is wrapped in a dropwizard Managed object and is tied to the lifecycle of the application.

```
public class SalApplication extends Application<SomeConf> {
...
private GuiceBundle<SomeConf> guiceBundle;
private MongoBundle<SomeConf> mongoBundle;
...

@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<SomeConf> bootstrap) {
// build bundles and add to bootstrap
...
}

@Override
public void run(SomeConf someConf, Environment env) throws Exception{
...
MongoClient client = mongoBundle.getClient();
MongoClientManager mongoDB = new MongoClientManager(client);
env.lifecycle().manage(mongoDB); //MongoClientManager implements Managed
}
```

My hiccup is, how do I get hold of the MongoClient object.
The object is supposed to be injected into my DAOs.
But **how can I access the MongoClient object from inside guice Module**.

If I construct another MongoClient object inside guice module, then what is the point of the Managed Object. I'm really confused.

Comment: The GuiceBundle you are using is coming from this component: https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice?

Comment: Yes. HubSpot/dropwizard-guice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simpler way to achieve what I needed.

I was previously using com.meltmedia.dropwizard.dropwizard-mongo, whose MongoBundle constructs the MongoClient, which had to be passed to my ManagedObject.

I stopped using it. Instead I'm constructing the MongoClient object myself using mongo-java-driver inside guice module, and is injected into the constructor of my managed object.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend writing your own Guice module. While the dropwizard-guice is quite useful it has not been updated since Feb 2017 and only supports up to version 1.0.0 of DW. A basic version of your module could look like this:

```
public class CustomModule implements Module {

    private final MongoClient mongoClient;

    public CustomModule(MongoClient mongoClient) {
        this.mongoClient = mongoClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Binder binder) {
        binder.bind(MongoClient.class).toInstance(mongoClient);
    }
}
```

Which then you can initialize from the "run" method in your Application class using the Guice standard methods:

```
public class SalApplication extends Application<SomeConf> {

    ...

    @Override
    public void run(SomeConf someConf, Environment env) throws Exception{

        Guice.createInjector(new CustomModule(mongoBundle.getClient());

        ...
    }
}
```